# Neo4j Java Driver issue

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using the Neo4j Java driver 1.7.5 version and I unable to find how to pass the charset from java driver docs/blog.

Please can you share how to pass the charset with the java driver?

Actually, I am having one issue with the Neo4j Java driver.

My spark job will create a couple of CSV's and persist them into HDFS. With Akka HTTP, I stream those files and run the load CSV Cypher queries. After some time I am getting the below error and unable to find the reason.

Here CSV's are partitioned into multiple files and these files contain a total of 53 million records.

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while executing te following
neo4j query
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
"http://cdp-dn27.stg.iad1.ccmteam.com:7111/ingestion-files/part-00000-121ed02d-6ebf-4958-9e8e-bd7b4337bda4-c000.csv"
AS param FIELDTERMINATOR "|"
MATCH (person1:Person {person_guid: param.user1}), (person2:Person
{person_guid: param.user2})
MERGE (person1)-[r:KNOWS]-(person2)
      SET r.last_tran_time = CASE WHEN toInteger(param.last_tran_date) >
coalesce(r.last_tran_time, 0) THEN toInteger(param.last_tran_date) ELSE
r.last_tran_time END
SET r.first_tran_time = CASE WHEN toInteger(param.first_tran_date) <
coalesce(r.first_tran_time, 9999999999) THEN
toInteger(param.first_tran_date) ELSE r.first_tran_time END
SET r.num_transactions = CASE WHEN EXISTS(r.num_transactions) THEN
r.num_transactions + toInteger(param.num_trans) ELSE
toInteger(param.num_trans) END

        at com.test.graphbuilder.dao.Neo4JDao.runQuery(Neo4JDao.scala:46)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.service.DataUpdateService$$anonfun$2.apply(DataUpdateService.scala:37)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.service.DataUpdateService$$anonfun$2.apply(DataUpdateService.scala:30)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:284)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.service.DataUpdateService.updateData(DataUpdateService.scala:30)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.service.GraphRefreshService$$anonfun$8.apply(GraphRefreshService.scala:49)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.service.GraphRefreshService$$anonfun$8.apply(GraphRefreshService.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:288)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.service.GraphRefreshService.refreshGraph(GraphRefreshService.scala:49)
        at com.test.graphbuilder.KafkaTrigger$.main(KafkaTrigger.scala:22)
        at com.test.graphbuilder.KafkaTrigger.main(KafkaTrigger.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at
org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:673)
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.DatabaseException: Error
occured in read-ahead thread
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:123)
        at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.blockingGet(InternalStatementResult.java:134)
        at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalStatementResult.consume(InternalStatementResult.java:117)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.dao.Neo4JDao$$anonfun$runQuery$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Neo4JDao.scala:33)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.dao.Neo4JDao$$anonfun$runQuery$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Neo4JDao.scala:31)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.util.AutoClosableUtil$.autoClose(AutoClosableUtil.scala:6)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.dao.Neo4JDao$$anonfun$runQuery$1.apply(Neo4JDao.scala:31)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.dao.Neo4JDao$$anonfun$runQuery$1.apply(Neo4JDao.scala:30)
        at
com.test.graphbuilder.util.AutoClosableUtil$.autoClose(AutoClosableUtil.scala:6)
        at com.test.graphbuilder.dao.Neo4JDao.runQuery(Neo4JDao.scala:30)
        ... 15 more
        Suppressed: org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil$InternalExceptionCause
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil.newNeo4jError(ErrorUtil.java:72)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageDispatcher.handleFailureMessage(InboundMessageDispatcher.java:105)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.v1.MessageReaderV1.unpackFailureMessage(MessageReaderV1.java:83)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.v1.MessageReaderV1.read(MessageReaderV1.java:59)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:83)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:35)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.MessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageDecoder.java:47)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1389)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1159)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1203)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1414)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:945)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:146)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
                at
org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks in advance. Please help me with this

Comment: The driver version is very outdated, you should upgrade to 4.x.
The stack trace is incomplete.
What do you need the charset for? `LOAD CSV` assumes only UTF-8 documents. You need to change the charset before loading it to Neo4j.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I thought LOAD CSV is not considering UTF-8.  I also updated a full stack trace from my log. Here I am getting the error message very generic. so I am unable to identify the issue.

Comment: `LOAD CSV` only supports UTF-8 encoded files: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#csv-file-format

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, the stack trace you posted is not complete. The beginning is missing.

Comment: What version of Neo4j server are you using?

Comment: I again update the stack trace, We are using the 3.3.1 community edition and java driver 1.7.5 version. thanks

Comment: Can you try again with a more recent Neo4j version (at least 3.5) and driver?